# Getting your assets to connect through the firewall, Silex

Tags: php, css, assets, firewall, silex

I got user authentication to work on a little project I am working on. However, all the pages behind the firewall can not get to my assets folder. So it has no CSS and won't get the images in that file tree either.

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
    'user' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/user',
        'form' => array(
            'login_path' => '/',
            'check_path' => '/user/login_check',
            'default_target_path' => '/user/user_area',
            'always_use_default_target_path' => true
        ),
        'users' => array(
            'user' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', '5FZ2Z8QIkA7UTZ4BYkoC+GsReLf569mSKDsfods6LYQ8t+a8EW9oaircfMpmaLbPBh4FOBiiFyLfuZmTSUwzZg=='),
        ),
    ),
),
```

));

And a sample of my css files in a twig

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--external css-->
<link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/scout-styles.css">
```

and my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I noticed that the assets now rout as `<link href="user/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">` tried making a user file to put my assets in but then that upset the routing.

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess file (or your redirect rules)?

Comment: This is all I have, I need to learn more about .htaccess `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: I think you just need to start your assets with the / character, have you tried that?

Comment: That worked! thanks! I wonder why that is.

Comment: That's because when the URI path does not start with the / character it means it's a relative URI path (relative to the current URI directory). So for instance an asset path of *assets/css/bootstrap.css* in the *http://example.com/user/som-page* URI, is looking for the file at the URI *http://example.com/user/assets/css/bootstrap.css*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's close this one.

It seems that the problem was within the URI path of the assets, they just need to start with the / character in order to make the path absolute to the site an not to the current URI path.